# How to make this python currency quote application using API work?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I made two different projects. One using tkinter to make GUI and the other one I was learning to use customtkinter. In this project I'm trying to combine the dollar, euro and bitcoin quote code with what I learned doing GUI using customtkinter. I don't exactly know how to get this to run right now. I've read the customtkinter documentation but I couldn't find the answer. If you can help me I will be grateful haha

```
import customtkinter
import requests

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("500x350")
root.title("Cotacao Krettina")

def pegar_cotacoes():
requisicao = requests.get('https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/last/USD-BRL,EUR-BRL,BTC-BRL')

    requisicao_dic = requisicao.json()
    
    cotacao_dolar = requisicao_dic ['USDBRL']['bid']
    cotacao_euro = requisicao_dic ['EURBRL']['bid']
    cotacao_bitcoin = requisicao_dic ['BTCBRL']['bid']
    
    
    texto = f'''
    Dolar: {cotacao_dolar}
    Euro: {cotacao_euro}
    Bitcoin: {cotacao_bitcoin}'''
    
    texto_cotacoes["text"] = texto

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Cotar!", command=pegar_cotacoes)
button.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

texto_cotacoes = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=root, width=120, height=25, corner_radius=8)
texto_cotacoes.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

root.mainloop()\
```

Comment: So what's the problem you are having? you didn't tell. Tell us what happens when you run that code and what is what you expect to happen. If you get an error tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: Use `texto_cotacoes.configure(text=texto)` instead of `texto_cotacoes["text"] = texto`.